# Only One Side Recorded With Asterisk Manager API

Tags: java, asterisk

I am using Asterisk-Java to send Manager API calls to monitor phone calls.  For some reason, when the file is finished, I only end up with one side of the conversation recorded.  Does anyone have any idea why this might be happening?  Here is my call:

```
Response response = connection.sendEventGeneratingAction(new MonitorAction(theChannel, filename, "wav", true));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oddly enough I ended up having to start and stop mixmon in the dialplan in order to accurately record the call.